# TYPO3 6.2 How to use Try-Catch Block

Tags: php, typo3, typo3-6.2.x

I just read an introduction to Exceptions in PHP and wanted to use them in my TYPO3 Extension, but I get an error when using this...

```
try{
   if(arrayEmpty){
        throw new Exception('Error Msg...');
   }
} catch (Exception $e){
  $this->addFlashMessage($e->getMessage());
}
```

> Fatal error: Class '...\Exception' not found in
>   /.../controller.php
>   on line ...

Do I have to put in some kind of namespace at the top of my php file or how should I make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are working with namespaces, it should be `throw new \Exception(...);`.

Comment: ahhh, I think that will solve my Problem indeed- thx!! I will try that later and mark your answer as accepted when it worked :)